# How to match columns by name and then insert new column if they matched

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Hi All I am having some trouble using vlook-up as I am very new to it.

I have a table (table 1) with Document Name and effective date and another table (table 2) with just the document names.

I am trying to use v-lookup to add the effective date of the matched document names to table 2.

I have tried

> =VLOOKUP(E3,'[Training Dossier - 20-Aug-2023.xls]Sheet'!$B$1:$F$632,2,FALSE)

However I keep getting #N/A as the return, any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So I'm assuming you are having issues with the way you are referencing the data.
Unless the name of the sheet is literally "Sheet" change it to "Sheet1" or whatever your sheet name is

```
=VLOOKUP(E3,'[Training Dossier - 20-Aug-2023.xls]Sheet1'!$B$1:$F$632,2,FALSE)
```

I would omit the row numbers to account for added data.

```
=VLOOKUP(E3,'[Training Dossier - 20-Aug-2023.xls]Sheet1'!$B:$F,2,FALSE)
```

Also if you are using tables you could use the table name in the reference.

```
=VLOOKUP(E3,'Training Dossier - 20-Aug-2023.xls!YourTableName[#Data],2,FALSE)
```

Be sure to change YouTableName to the name of the table.